# Flutter Error - FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'storage/emulated/0/myDir' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am try to create a folder in my external android device's external storage (path: storage/emulated/0/myDir). But I keep getting the same error. I have searched everywhere on the internet for a solution and have not found one.

I have the following permissions in my Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
```

And I have the following code the application tag of my Android Manifest

```
<application
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
</application>
```

Any suggestions of what is going wrong?

Comment: What's  target and compile sdk in manifest file ?

Comment: And what's the Gradle version you are using ?

Comment: And Android version op used device. `But I keep getting the same error. ` Which error? Put all info in your post please.

Comment: The target sdk is 30, I am using gradle version 4.2.1 and the error I keep getting is FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'storage/emulated/0/myDir' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

Comment: Anybody got solution???

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved this problem with the following solutions:
For android 10/Q, I have added this permission in the androidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
```

and add this line in **application** tag:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

like this:

```
<application
    ...
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

For android 11/R, add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

In app-user permission handler I'm checking permissions with the following function:

```
Future<bool> _hasAcceptedPermissions() async {
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  if (await _requestPermission(Permission.storage) &&
      // access media location needed for android 10/Q
      await _requestPermission(Permission.accessMediaLocation) &&
      // manage external storage needed for android 11/R
      await _requestPermission(Permission.manageExternalStorage)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  if (await _requestPermission(Permission.photos)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} else {
  // not android or ios
  return false;
}}
```

Comment: if some one is still getting error, you can try adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> instead of <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: if you encounter a build error using the android 11 solution , you need to add the tools namespace to the manifest file by declaring it like this <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
</manifest>

Answer (score 1):

Due to recent changes in android OS we have to evolve our appp,
I found the solution---
you have to enter the following in your project

1. in manifest- uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
2. in your app- user permission handler

   bool permission =
   await requestPermissionHelper(Permission.manageExternalStorage);

Answer (score 0):

```
in All Manifest Files

1. <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" **xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools**"

2. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>

Future getStoragePermission() async {
  PermissionStatus status = await Permission.storage.request();
  //PermissionStatus status1 = await Permission.accessMediaLocation.request();
  PermissionStatus status2 = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
  print('status $status   -> $status2');
  if (status.isGranted && status2.isGranted) {
    return true;
  } else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied || status2.isPermanentlyDenied) {
    await openAppSettings();
  } else if (status.isDenied) {
    print('Permission Denied');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, I was getting the same error and none of the solutions provided online worked.

The actual problem was the file name.

My file name contained the character colon(`:`). Removing it from the file name solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Figured out the problem, android has updated android 11 to include scoped storage so requires an extra permission from the app user

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

Comment: I have the same problem... @tluangahauhnar found any solution?